# Why do new photos take so long to show up in the Gallery?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, gallery, camera

If I take some photos, and then go to the Gallery app, those photos do not always appear immediately.  I've tried causing the Gallery to refresh, but the images simply do not appear for more than 15 minutes.  I can open the Camera app again and browse through them, so I know they have been stored.

Is there a way to eliminate the latency between when a photo is taken using Camera and when it appears in Gallery?

Comment: How long is "quite some time"? I have an issue with the gallery also, but I don't think it's quite the same. Are you talking about minutes, hours, days?

Comment: It was in the range of minutes.  I would take a series of photos and close the camera app.  Moments (a minute or two ) later I would want to review those photos in the gallery app.  Sometimes they would not appear, and not until several minutes (>15) later would I be able to view them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The delay is because the Android media scanner process doesn't run constantly. There's an app in the market to force it to run -- http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.addz.mediascanner

I haven't used this app personally, but it is highly rated.

Answer (score 1):

Heres an alternative to the 3D Gallery its a 2dGallery they updates very fast!

http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=377221&d=1281435373

Enjoy!

p.s - if t doesn't work you might need to login / register on XDA and then download it but its worth it! I download this and then just remove the other gallery since its laggy.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO there are these ways to decrease the latency:

1. Use CyanogenMod (it's much faster than stock Android)
2. Get a faster phone (i.g. Nexus One)
3. Remove Appkillers

Else you might just have to wait for an update of the Gallery app.

Comment: +1 on removing app killers. I noticed the same behavior until I stopped using app killers.

Comment: Actually, I don't think app killers have anything to do with this. I don't use app killers and notice the same latency.

Comment: -1, the OP is not talking about "latency" as in having a laggy gallery, instead he was asking latency as in "new photos not immediately appearing in the gallery"

Answer (score 0):

There are certain actions that always set the media scanner running when you carry them out.

If you attach your phone to a PC and mount it as a USB drive, the media scanner will run after you unplug.

Most file managers will notify the media scanner if you use them to move files around.

A couple of the other apps I use, like Image Transfer set the media scanner runnning (presumably to check that they've got up to date info on what media has changed recently).