# How to set my wallpaper from my Dropbox?

Tags: gallery, wallpaper, dropbox

I have copied a bunch of images into my Dropbox on my pc and sync'd them to my phone. Does anyone know how to use these images for wallpapers on my phone?

The only way I can think of is that I can use something like Astro to copy the file to my gallery locally on the phone, or to share my dropbox pictures folder on the web and browse to it.

Although copying the file into dropbox and then copying it again seems crazy. Is there a better option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right I just played with trying to set a Dropbox image as my wallpaper, and can't believe that there isn't an easier way. Part of the problem seems to be that if you Open a dropbox image, it isn't sent to the Gallery or the system default image viewer (which would let you do things like set as wallpaper) but Dropbox uses its own (HTML?) viewer.

There are feature requests in Dropbox's "Votebox" that are requesting features that would fix this. It's probably worth heading over there and letting them know that you'd like this feature, this option looks like the most likely (but you can just go to [Votebox](https://www.dropbox.com/votebox) and search for Android to see all the relevant ones):

[Add Dropbox photos to Android gallery](https://www.dropbox.com/votebox/1778/add-dropbox-photos-to-android-gallery)

**Update:** If you download photos from Dropbox, they do appear in the gallery in a folder called "Photos". Now that they're in the Gallery, you can set them as wallpaper the same as normal. You might need to force the media scanner to start before they'll show up in the gallery, this [previous question has options for forcing that to run](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/125/gallery-latency).

Comment: TUrns out that when you download an image from your Dropbox it's saved into your gallery, but only the android gallery and not the cooliris gallery app

Comment: Aah, that's odd. I wasn't seeing any of them in the Gallery while I was testing, but I can now, in their own "Photos" folder. I did reboot my phone over the weekend, so I wonder if that kicked the gallery into finding them?

Comment: How exactly do you "Download"?  I don't see that option anywhere from a long or short press.

Answer (score 1):

When I select an image from Dropbox, it opens to be viewed. Then if I press *and hold* the image, I'm given the option to Open, Download, Share or Delete the image. If I choose Open, the image opens in a view similar to the Gallery in which I can press menu, then Set as and finally, Wallpaper.

This still requires several steps but you never have to actually download the image from Dropbox.

Comment: Press and hold only gives me "Share", "Favorite", "Delete", "Rename", "Move" and "Export" none of which have the desired effect.   There is no "Open" or "Download" option.  Now what?

Answer (score 0):

HTC One V phone. I e-mail the photo from Dropbox to myself. Open pic, press, hold, release and your options are there. Set as wallpaper and photo saves in gallery (all photos) or just download.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am several years late, but just in case someone is still looking for a solution for this, I will leave this app here, that I have just found:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.simonesessa.changer

It seems to get the job done, and even has settings for ordering and shuffling.
(It's a bit confusing whether you need to pay if you only use one account, I'm not sure whether it stays free after the trial period or not.)

Answer (score 0):

I know is is an old question but it seems Dropbox still hasn't fixed this.  I managed to find a way to do it through Photos:

1. Open Dropbox and find image
2. ...
3. Export
4. Upload to Photos
5. Upload (Photos account must be setup)
6. ... (Top right)
7. Use As
8. Wallpaper
9. Tick Set Wallpaper

Done

Comment: This could be a solution (one of dozens, since Dropbox exports to that many different locations/apps/tools on my phone, most of which allow wallpaper), but not a solution from Dropbox, which is the intent of the original poster. I would have kept Google out of the middle of the transaction, in any case.

Answer (score -1):

Open dropbox view camera uploads press circled arrow of chosen pic, select more, then select open with, choose 'gallery' wait for jpg to open then press your own phone menu button ( in samsung bottom left corner) select set as then proceed for wallpaper or home screen. :)