# Not all images showing up in gallery

Tags: gallery, thumbnails

Some photos do not show up in the gallery app. I can find those particular shots trough the camera app for some reason, and using a file-browser I can find them too. But they will not show up in the gallery.

I found [this topic about thumbnail problems](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5471/problem-with-my-thumbnails-in-gallery). I did what the answer suggested, although it was not exactly the same problem. Sadly it didn't help.

Another topic [talks about latency](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/125/gallery-latency). I don't think "use a quicker phone" is a solution (desire-z is quick enough), and we're talking about a different problem: I have pictures from yesterday not shown, but from today are in there, so the scanner has been running.

**Why don't all my photos show in the gallery?**

edit: the images do not seem any different. They are all saved in

```
/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/100MEDIA
```

called

```
IMAG0402  //visible
IMAG0403  //invis
IMAG0404  //invis
IMAG0405  //invis
IMAG0406  //visible
```

(I checked this trough ASTRO browser)

Comment: I assume the missing ones are stored in the same place as ones that show up, and are named similarly?

Comment: yes, i'll add an example with filesnames

Comment: I'm getting the exact same problem!!! Sometimes my photos don't show up at all till I connect to a computer. THey all show with a file manager though :/

Comment: simple check - make sure how device connecting mode - is it like a camera or media mode. In media mode you could do file operations(cut,copy) properly

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try deleting the `/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/.thumbnails` folder and rebooting your phone.  You may need to clear data for Media Storage and possibly the Gallery app/anything related as well.

Comment: That did help for the old pictures, but it doesn't for some new shots. That might be the latency one of the other questions talks about, so I'll give it a moment :)

Comment: it DID fix my picasaweb problem by the way. 0_o    http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7013/picasa-in-gallery-not-linked-cant-open-picasa-folders/7092#7092

Comment: Yeah, I think it's more Android OS latency than device slowness.  It doesn't seem to scan for new media files very well.  The camera should really trigger something to add the new photo to Android's "scanned media" list, or something like that.

Comment: But how long is latency? It's been over an hour, and although al the deleting and rebooting has made the older shots come up, but my testshot is still gone (over an hour). That's something else than latency maybe?

Comment: Yeah I think it's just bad terminology.  I think the OS hasn't scanned for media since you took that photo, and so it only "knows about" the older photos.  One thing you could try is going to `Settings -> SD card and phone storage` and hitting **Unmount SD card**, then immediately re-mounting it.  The re-mount should trigger a media scan.

Comment: Hmm. Now it did show up, but somewhere random, so I couldn't find it at first. But it should have scanned, I mean, I can understand slowness, but an hour must be something else. The scan must be triggered allready. This morning I had some not show up, but newer ones that did. Anyway, this answer looks like the best I'll get :)

Comment: @Nanne: though I don't know about the specifics of media scanner, I doubt that the media scanning is triggered at fixed time intervals, it is more likely to be triggered when a possibly relevant file are added to SD card (e.g. if you download something, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Turns out my `.thumbnails` folder was not inside my `/DCIM` folder. I moved it back inside, restarted the phone and it's been fine since.

Answer (score 1):

[SDrescan](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bero.sdrescan) is small and easy to use.

If you happen to have a custom ROM with dev tools installed, use that:
Launch "Dev Tools" => Media Provider => Scan SDcard

Both ways hide the manual steps from you and you can't delete stuff by mistake this way.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was enough to just open `/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/.thumbnails` folder using [Astro File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro). I scrolled down and up through all files within this folder and I've seen system showing message "Creating thumbnails". Once I returned to Gallery, even without restarting phone, all camera pictures and videos displayed properly.

You could also try opening a few of the photos in the DCIM folder using Astro in order to trigger a refresh.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to work for me. Wouldn't that 'creating thumbnails' be for the thumbnails-of-the-thumbnails that astro needs, not the thumbnails self (the files allready in that directory, that are thumbs of your photos?)