# Why can't my phone find pictures or music files suddenly?

Tags: cyanogenmod, music, images, files

I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace with its official CyanogenMod nightly build. And suddenly, it doesn't "see" my pictures, videos or music files. They don't show:

1. while selecting a notification/ring tone & default music player,
2. while viewing pictures in QuickPic or the default gallery, and
3. on Go Launcher Ex's videos and music finder feature.

However, ES File Explorer, the default File Manager, and PowerAmp clearly show the said types of files. I've done a NANDROID backup, wiped the partitions then restored the backup, still no go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah, cripes. I don't know what on Earth put this `.nomedia` file on the root of my SD card. Problem fixed.

Comment: Don't forget to "Accept" this as the answer (when you're allowed) to act as a signpost for future readers. I'm sure someone else will run into this issue, too.

Comment: Looks like a recent update to ROM Manager could be the culprit: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.rommanager&hl=en (see latest in "What's New" section)

Comment: Ha! That might be right. Thanks. And I need 22 more hours so I may accept this, but I will.

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been driving me insane.  It's happened previously on Samsung Galaxy S4 and again on my S6 edge.

**Issue: Images missing from Gallery app or Music missing from music player app.**

Having tried everything from using ES explorer to move files to wiping the cache partition, there's a simple **solution**:

> > Plug your device into a PC. Identify the folders that are not showing (i.e., DCIM and Music). RENAME these to something else (such as "DCIM2" and "Music2").  The files will reappear.

I then renamed the folders back to "DCIM" and "Music".  It took 48 hours of online searches, learning about the 'emulated' folder etc - but this was the simple solution. I guess it reindexes the folders and makes them be found again by the appropriate apps.

Hope this helps.

**David**